# is there problem in my code that my listview didnt show any thing?

Tags: sqlite, listview, kotlin

its my first app that i write with kotlin.
this app is about contact.
i write this code but i dont why my  listview didnt show.i use the database two table and related with each other and insert data and show in  listview but my  listview didint show.
Any body knows whats my problem?

this is my code of database:

```
    class DBhelper(context:Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context,"My table",null,1){

 override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        var a=("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name("+"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+"firstName TEXT NOT NULL,"+"lastName TEXT NOT NULL)")
        db?.execSQL(a)
        var b=("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS number("+"id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+"phoneNumbers TEXT NOT NULL,"+"userId Int,"+"FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES name(_id))")
        db?.execSQL(b)
    }
    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

and this my main activity

```
package com.example.contact1
import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
import com.example.myapplication.DBhelper
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var db: SQLiteDatabase?=null
    var cursor: Cursor?=null
    var cursorN: Cursor?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        faB.setOnClickListener {
            var intent= Intent(this,page2::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        var sqlite= DBhelper(this)
        db=sqlite.readableDatabase
        cursor=db?.query("name", arrayOf("_id","firstName","lastName"),null,null,null,null,null)
        cursorN=db?.query("number", arrayOf("id","phoneNumbers"),null,null,null,null,null)
        var adapter= SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor, arrayOf("lastName"),IntArray(android.R.id.text1),0)

        listView.adapter=adapter
        }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        db!!.close()
        cursor!!.close()

        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

and this code of acticity 2 in name of page2:

```
package com.example.contact1

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Intent
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Selection
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.myapplication.DBhelper
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_page2.*
import java.lang.Exception
import java.util.logging.Logger
import kotlin.math.log

class page2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    var sqlite= DBhelper(this)
    var db: SQLiteDatabase?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2)
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener{

            db=sqlite.writableDatabase


            val contentValues1= ContentValues()

                if(editTextFirstName.text.isEmpty()&& editTextLastName.text.isEmpty() )
                { contentValues1.put("firstName","unknown")
                }else{ contentValues1.put("firstName",editTextFirstName.text.toString()) }

            contentValues1.put("lastName",editTextLastName.text.toString())
           db!!.insert("name",null,contentValues1)

            val contentValues2= ContentValues()
            contentValues2.put("phoneNumbers",editTextPhone.text.toString())

          var s="select _id FROM name WHERE firstName='"+contentValues1+"' AND lastname='"+contentValues1+""
         contentValues2.put("userId",s)

            db!!.insert("number", null,contentValues2)
            Toast.makeText(this,"saved succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


            }

        buttonDiscard.setOnClickListener {  }
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        db!!.close()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

when i save contact and click back i didint see any thing like this:
http://uupload.ir/files/f936_a.jpg

and when close app and open again i see this
http://uupload.ir/files/zr1z_b.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `LayoutManager` for your `listView`:

```
listView.adapter=adapter
listView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager()
```

Check here to see how `LayoutManager` works: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html

Comment: thank u but i think this is for RecyclerView and i used the listview
but i try it and i dont find any thing that say we can use this for listViwe.thank u so much to take time for me